# Generic factory definition options

Tags: java, generics, factory

What is a rule of thumb to define a generic factory? What is difference in implementation and usage?

Option 1:

```
public interface ScheduleFactory<V, T extends Period<V>> {
     Schedule<V,T> fromConfigurationString(String configurationString);
}
```

Option 2:

```
public interface ScheduleFactory {
     <V, T extends Period<V>> Schedule<V,T> fromConfigurationString(String configurationString);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first way, you create a `ScheduleFactory` with a specific `V` and `T`, and thereafter that factory object can only return `Schedule<V, T>`.

In the second way, you create a `ScheduleFactory` object, and that single factory object can then create `Schedule<V, T>` for different `V`s and `T`s each call.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference is **Type inference**

Generic method : it helps the java compiler to look at the generic method invocation to determine which type argument that make the invocation are applicable.

Generic class : the constraint of type affects to whole class/interface and each method you declared.